# Expand ranges to values in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I have a table with 3 columns:

- range_start
- range_end
- range_id

and need to generate one table with two columns where

- in first column are values from those ranges and
- in second column is the id of the range from which the value comes from.

Comment: HI, Please take the [tour], read [ask].  Edit the question and show the table definitions, example data, and what you have attempted.  thanks

Comment: Please provide sample input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivial using XML tools.

Using table `test`, created with the following statement:

```
create table test (range_start, range_end, range_id) as
  select 1, 4, 100 from dual union all
  select 7, 9, 101 from dual
;
```

Query and output:

```
select t.range_id, xmlcast(x.column_value as number) as value
from   test t, xmltable(t.range_start || ' to ' || t.range_end) x
order  by range_id, value   --  if needed
;

  RANGE_ID      VALUE
---------- ----------
       100          1
       100          2
       100          3
       100          4
       101          7
       101          8
       101          9
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a row generator question. Sample data in lines #1 - 4; query begins at line #5.

```
SQL> with test (range_start, range_end, range_id) as
  2    (select 1, 4, 100 from dual union all
  3     select 7, 9, 101 from dual
  4    )
  5  select range_id,
  6         range_start + column_value - 1 range_value
  7  from test cross join
  8    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  9                        connect by level <= range_end - range_start + 1
 10                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 11  order by range_id, range_value;

  RANGE_ID RANGE_VALUE
---------- -----------
       100           1
       100           2
       100           3
       100           4
       101           7
       101           8
       101           9

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```